# Unable to authenticate to ADLS using python due to AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Tags: python, authentication, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I am using below python authentication script to connect to ADLS using service principal details but it keeps throwing exception:`azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.`

The role assigned to me is "Storage blob data owner" and not sure what is missing?

**Python Code:**

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

TENANT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME), credential=credential)
print(service_client.primary_endpoint) # Can see the primary endpoint. 
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client("my-container")
file_system_client.create_directory("test-dir") #Throwing the (AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) error.
print("test directory created.")
```

**Complete Trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_path_client.py", line 200, in _create
    return self._client.path.create(**options)
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_generated/operations/_path_operations.py", line 248, in create
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:80605399-e01f-0038-2cd2-0a4210000000
Time:2021-02-24T17:25:49.0969802Z

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adls_client.py", line 30, in <module>
    file_system_client.create_directory("test-dir")
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_file_system_client.py", line 540, in create_directory
    directory_client.create_directory(metadata=metadata, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_data_lake_directory_client.py", line 160, in create_directory
    return self._create('directory', metadata=metadata, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_path_client.py", line 202, in _create
    process_storage_error(error)
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_deserialize.py", line 150, in process_storage_error
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

Comment: Your code is no problem. But RBAC role does not take effect immediately, you need to wait a while. After a while it should work. Can you reproduce your error now?

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error:

[image]

I am pretty sure your code is no problem, and, `Storage blob data owner` is the right RBAC role of your AD app. I think maybe the problem comes from the RBAC role does not take effect immediately, you need to wait a while. And then it should work.